# why does maven search for parent_project:pom:${revision} when building this child_project?

Tags: parent-child, maven-3, versioning, build-error, revision

**background**

directory layout

```
|
|`parent_project/pom.xml
|
|`child_project/pom.xml
```

parent pom

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent_project</artifactId>
    <version>${revision}</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
</project>
```

child pom

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <artifactId>parent_project</artifactId>
        <groupId>org.example</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>child_project</artifactId>
    <version>${revision}</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
</project>
```

**steps to produce issue**

1. build parent

```
mvn clean install -Drevision=1.0-SNAPSHOT -U -f pom.xml
```

2. build child

```
mvn clean install -Drevision=1.0-SNAPSHOT -U -f pom.xml
```

3. get error

```
Could not find artifact org.example:parent_project:pom:${revision} in remote-repo (url)
```

**question**

I specified the parent version as 1.0-SNAPSHOT in the child's parent block, so why is maven trying to find `org.example:parent_project:pom:${revision}`?

[image: the ${revision} folder is added to the local repository parent_project directory when maven starts looking for ${revision} while building the child_project]

*the ${revision} directory is added to .m2/repository/.../parent_project/ when maven starts looking for parent_project:pom:${revision} while building child_project*

Answer (score 0):

answer reworked, checkout the links at the end for documentations `multi module project` and `ci friendly links` with `revision` parameter.

Example (building parent builds also children, building a child just builds that child):

**directory layout**

- ...\parent\pom.xml
- ...\parent\child1\pom.xml
- ...\parent\child2\pom.xml

**parent pom**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>so</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent-project</artifactId>
    <version>${revision}</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <properties>
        <revision>1.0.0-DEFAULT</revision>
    </properties>

    <modules>
        <module>child1-project</module>
        <module>child2-project</module>
    </modules>

</project>
```

**child poms (also packaging pom to create a minimal example)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>parent-project</groupId>
    <artifactId>child1-project</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>so</groupId>
        <artifactId>parent-project</artifactId>
        <version>${revision}</version>
    </parent>

</project>
```

and

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>parent-project</groupId>
    <artifactId>child2-project</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>so</groupId>
        <artifactId>parent-project</artifactId>
        <version>${revision}</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>parent-project</groupId>
            <artifactId>child1-project</artifactId>
            <version>${revision}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

**links**

- https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-modules.html
- https://books.sonatype.com/mvnex-book/reference/multimodule.html
- https://maven.apache.org/maven-ci-friendly.html